# Passing variable from Bash to psql

Tags: bash

I'm having some trouble with passing a variable from Bash to a `psql` command. Can't figure out where to place quotes or parantheses where needed

I'm essentially trying to insert today's date into a date column on a PostGres table

```
today=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")

echo $today
#10-05-2015

psql -h hostname -U admin -d db-p 5439 -c \
"INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount) VALUES ("$today", $rowcount)";
```

I've tried calling `$today` without the quotes and a few other variations, but can't get it to pass what I want, which is `10-05-2015`. Instead, the value `-2010` is being inserted, which is essentialy 10 minus 5 minus 2015...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
"INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount) VALUES (\"$today\", $rowcount)";
```

Without escaping them, they are being interpreted by the shell as the end of the string. Then the date is being inserted (as the shell is concatenating the previous string with this non-quoted-string), and finally, after the date, the shell sees another string for the rest of the SQL command and concatenates with the others.

So what psql was receiving was

```
INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount) VALUES (10-05-2015, <rowcount_value>)
```

and it sees it as integers, so psql resolves that you want to insert the integer `-2010`.

After properly quoting it, psql receives:

```
INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount) VALUES ("10-05-2015", <rowcount_value>)
```

Comment: I have another escaping-related question. Query is a bit different, and looks like `"BEGIN READ WRITE; COPY public.tablename FROM 's3://location/filename.txt' "` I want to create a variable like `locationname=directoryname` and call it in the last part there. So the query would look like `"BEGIN READ WRITE; COPY public.tablename FROM 's3://$locationname/filename.txt' "` How do I escape the quote this time?

Comment: @simplycoding no need to escape quotes this time

Answer (score 2):

To embed quotation marks within quotation marks you need to escape them by preceding them with backslashes (`\`).  As it is now, bash interprets the quotation mark immediately left of `$today` as terminating a quoted string, and the one immediately right as starting a new one.

This appears to be what you're trying to do:

```
psql -h hostname -U admin -d db-p 5439 -c \
"INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount) VALUES (\"$today\", $rowcount)";
```

Alternatively, you could use apostrophes inside the command instead, which would be more standard SQL:

```
psql -h hostname -U admin -d db-p 5439 -c \
"INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount) VALUES ('$today', $rowcount)";
```

You cannot use apostrophes to quote the whole command, however, because that would suppress expansion of `$today`.

Answer (score 1):

The given answers are correct and they will work for your queries, but interpolating bash variables like that can still fail if the string itself contains quotes. The easier and safer alternative is to use Postgres' [dollar-quoted strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)

For your query, you can do:

```bash
today=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")

psql -h hostname -U admin -d db-p 5439 -c \
"INSERT INTO public.log_table (day, rowcount)
VALUES (\$\$ $today \$\$, $rowcount)";
```

More details: https://textquery.app/2022/07/15/properly-escape-postgres-sql-queries-bash/